# App Service HTTP/2 Not Working

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have HTTP Version set to 2.0, but App Service is acting like it is not.

I'm using https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test to test and it says `Negative! <site> does not support HTTP/2.0.`

Chrome is also using HTTP/1.1.

It looks like this is affecting all apps in the App Service Plan. I have 2 currently and neither have working HTTP/2. I added a third and it doesn't support HTTP/2 either. I have HTTPS setup on both apps and my requests are using HTTPS.

I've tried all sorts of combinations of changing the setting and restarting. I've tried stopping both apps and then restarting them.

Comment: Have you enabled HTTP/2 for your webapp?

Comment: Yes? In the App Service's Application Settings I have HTTP version set to 2.0.

Comment: Suggesting you to check this link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/04/13/announcing-http2-support-in-azure-app-service/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Azure support and they found an issue with the server my app service was hosted on. They were able to fix the issue and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I test in my site and get the same error message with you. However after waiting for serveral minutes, it will turn to HTTP/2.

As you have tested, go to App Service's Application Settings and set the HTTP version to 2.0. It may caused by the response delay.

[image]

If you want to ensure it, as Zahid said, you could refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/04/13/announcing-http2-support-in-azure-app-service/) to check if the `http20Enable` attibute value is `true`.

Comment: I've looked at the resource explorer and it does say `"http20Enabled": true`. It has been a couple days now and the tester and Chrome still won't use HTTP 2.0.

Answer (score -1):

Azure is just starting releasing the full HTTP/2 support.
HTTP/2 is supported as HTTP Server on AppService but the ILB (Reverse-proxy) router doesn't support on the client side the HTTP/2.
So the HTTP/2 is not available end to end because of the internal reverse-proxy (ARR) but they are migration on YARP Project with support HTTP/2 and gRPC.